# Dynamic change the tab content

Tags: php, html

[image]

I would like to know how to retrieve some new activity like the stackoverflow example? for example, if someone insert into the database, i can reflect it on the other user .

Also, if i want to dynamic change the tab content , such as when there is 1 new activity  it is (1) title, i can simply using `<title> <? echo $new; ?> title</title>`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to send Ajax request to poll periodically for any changes. The server side call will check for any new activities and send appropriate response such as number of activities. You can handle the response and update the title.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "get_update.php",      
  success: function(data){
    $(title).html(data); // data = "2 new activities"
  }
});
```

Comment: i have to set the time of request?(eg. 1 min/check) as i don't notice in your code? thanks

Comment: Yes. you may use javascript function `setInterval`.